# Texto por defecto en input

Tags: php

Tenía una duda sobre un formulario que no sé solucionar. Estoy intentando hacer que al darle click a un link en una página, me lleve a otra que contiene un formulario, y que en un input en concreto de ese formulario me ponga un texto por defecto solo si se ha entrado a la página desde el link.

En este caso, por ejemplo, quiero que al hacer click en el link me lleve a formulario.php y que ponga un texto por defecto en el input name="destinatario"

link.php

```
<a href="formulario.php">Texto</a>
```

formulario.php

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post">
       <span>Destinatario </span><input type="text" name="destinatario">
       <span>Asunto</span><input type="text" name="asunto">
       <span>Mensaje</span><input type="text" name="texto">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poner un texto por defecto en un `<input>` se hace poniendo `placeholder="Texto por defecto"`.

```
<input type="text" name="destinatario" placeholder="Texto por defecto">
```

Si lo que quieres es poner un valor por defecto se hace poniendo `value="Valor por defecto"`.

```
<input type="text" name="destinatario" value="Valor por defecto">
```

Y si lo que quieres es que ponga el valor o el texto dependiendo de la página que venga, es decir, si viene de index.php que ponga "Hola" y si viene de link.php que ponga "Adios" tienes que usar

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

y diferenciar en el formulario.

```
<?php
   $url_anterior = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
<form action="enviar.php" method="post">
<?php if($url_anterior == "index.php"){ ?>
   <span>Destinatario </span><input type="text" name="destinatario" value="Hola">
<?php }else{ ?>
   <span>Destinatario </span><input type="text" name="destinatario" value="Adios">
<?php } ?>
   <span>Asunto</span><input type="text" name="asunto">
   <span>Mensaje</span><input type="text" name="texto">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: A eso me refería muchas gracias!